# Open source alternative for dot net

Tags: .net, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.net open source and running platform choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374934/net-open-source-and-running-platform-choices)

Can any one tell me which is the perfect open source alternative for 
.NET.

Comment: Also the definition of 'perfect' when applied to software is highly subjective. mono is less perfect than .net, which is also not perfect. Practicability is usually a better goal than perfection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Also you are probably not aware but Microsoft has published the [source code of the .NET Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx) itself so why looking for an alternative?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't that code for view only, you cannot manipulate it etc.

Comment: @Marcus, yes it's for viewing and debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 2):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an open source .NET implementation.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Have a look at mono project , but a perfect one doesn't exists

Answer (score 1):

Mono is certainly the best open source .net implementation, but I would not suggest it as "perfect" (what you were asking for). When I compared it with MS.net it was definitely not as fast and you don't get all the features that MS offers. You should read about these things a bit more before commiting to Mono.

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) - in their own [words](http://www.mono-project.com/What_is_Mono):

> Mono is a software platform designed
>   to allow developers to easily create
>   cross platform applications. It is an
>   open source implementation of
>   Microsoft's .Net Framework based on
>   the ECMA standards for C# and the
>   Common Language Runtime. We feel that
>   by embracing a successful,
>   standardized software platform, we can
>   lower the barriers to producing great
>   applications for Linux.